# MVC set foreign key without dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm having issues when creating a new db object using EF. It has a foreign key which, when using the preset views, is set using a dropdown menu.

```
@Html.DropDownList("ParentID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

The issue is that I don't want to edit this value, it needs to be set in the controller but I cannot access the value.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    //I don't want a select list ParentID needs to be passed from the parent.
    ViewBag.ParentID = new SelectList(db.Parents, "ParentID", "ParentName"); 
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ChildID,ParentID,ChildName")] Child child)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //How do I set child.ParentID without a select list???
        db.Child.Add(child);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.ParentID = new SelectList(db.Parents, "ParentID", "ParentName", child.ParentID); //I don't need this
    return View(child);
}
```

What's the usual way this is achieved?

Comment: The question is where do you wanna get parentId from?is it passed to `Create` action(which makes sense in your case)

Comment: Make the method `public ActionResult Create(int ID)` and return a model to the view (with the `ParentId` set to the value of `ID`), then in the view use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ParentId)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanna pass `ParentID` from another `Action Method` but i wonder why you wanted to do that by means of `SelectList` (if there is no selection out there) though.

```
public ActionResult Create(int ParentID)
{
    //I don't want a select list ParentID needs to be passed from the parent.
    ViewBag.ParentID = ParentID; 
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ChildID,ParentID,ChildName")] Child child)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //How do I set child.ParentID without a select list???
        db.Child.Add(child);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("List");
}
```

And in the View :

```
 @Html.Hidden("ParentID", (object) ViewBag.ParentID)
```

i think it should be the way to go.

Comment: `@Html.Hidden("ParentID", ViewBag.ParentID)` causes error: HtmlHelper<Child> has no applicable method named 'Hidden' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: Also can't access the id to pass `@Html.ActionLink("Create New Child", "Create", new { id = Model.SingleOrDefault().Parent.ParentID })` as Model is an empty collection

Comment: Try to cast to `object` as it is dynamic expression.see edited answer.

Comment: Ok try to check why model is empty.

Comment: It's empty because no items have been added to it. The ParentID would be easy to access if there were items in the collection. The problem is how to add the first item.

Comment: I used the ViewBag and passed ParentID to the Index view and from there passed it to the Create view. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to implement an Edit action (or better 2 Edit actions one for getting and one for posting data).

Then you should define your scenario.. that is, you should declare if you want have the possibility to change current "parent" of your child entity in the edit form, or instead you desire current parent it is fixed once child entity was created.

Anyway, you should leave the "create" action and view as they were without changes. It is particularly important that the parentIDs be collected in a dropdownlist, because this control allows you to select among multiple values, and when you create a "child" entity, it is arguable you need to select among multiple parents.

As far as concern about "edit" actions, you may implement the following:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? cId)
{

    if (id == null)
    {
       return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Child child = db.Child.Find(cId);
    if (child == null)
    {
       return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.ParentID = new SelectList(db.Parents, "ParentID", "ParentName"); 
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ChildID,ParentID,ChildName")] Child child)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Child.Add(child);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    //You need this, because if you want change parent you can do it selecting from parents list
    ViewBag.ParentID = new SelectList(db.Parents, "ParentID", "ParentName", child.ParentID); 
    return View(child);
}
```

If you want avoid to modify your child's current parent once it is assigned first time created child entity, then it needs add a "disable" attribute at your dropdownlist control as it follows..

```
@Html.DropDownList("ParentID", null, htmlAttributes:  new { @disabled = "disabled" } })
```